# I need to use silverlight in tor

Tags: blocked-services

But I can't find any useful information on how to achieve this. I understand the reasons why it is disabled but I can't see any way of enabling this plug-in or installing it direct to the browser.

I am not very technically knowledgable so a step by step guide would be particularly helpful.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a routing middlebox - anf this is the **only** way : you will have network traffic leaks othervise due to the fact that all the plugins can bypass its host browser's settings